# Constructing a function using the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to use the proof of the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem to construct a a bijection between $A = (0, 1)$ and $B = [0, 1]$.

I need two injective functions to do so. 
My initial guess is that the bijective function, $h(x)$, will be a piecewise function. Looking at the proof, I think it's a good idea to trace the ancestry of  different numbers to attempt to construct a function. I'm given a hint suggesting me to trace the ancestry of $\frac{4}{9}$, and doing so, I get:

$\frac{4}{9} = g(x) \rightarrow x = \frac{1}{3}$

$\frac{1}{3} = f(x) \rightarrow x = 0$

$0 = g(x) \rightarrow x = -3$, which is no longer in the interval, so I do not need to trace back any further.

I am really unsure of how this helps me. I have the proof of the theorem, and I see the construction of the bijection say $h(a)$ equals $f(a)$ if $a$ has an oldest ancestor in $A$ or $a$ has no oldest ancestor, and $h(a) = b$ otherwise. I thought maybe finding two points and making a linear function could work, but I have no reason to think that $h(x)$ is linear. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Note that $g(x)=0$ doesn't even make sense in this context, since $g$ is a function whose codomain does not contain $0$. (Which is why you end up "outside the domain".)

Comment: So the eldest ancestor of 4/9 is in A, right? And that means h(4/9) = f(4/9) = 4/9.

Comment: There are several ways of approaching this problem. I don't know what proof of the Cantor–Bernstein theorem you're referring to, so I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: My post has been updated with the proof. Does it make sense ?

Comment: I don't know if you've seen this before, and this doesn't answer your question, but the proof you're using is explained beautifully if you search on "dog" in math.brown.edu/~res/infinity.pdf.

Comment: I had not seen that before. It is a very creative explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual proof goes like this. Let $S \subseteq A$ be a set such that $$g(B\setminus f(S)) = A \setminus S$$

Such a set exists because of Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorem.

Then define $h : A \to B$ as $$h(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $x \in S$} \\
g^{-1}(x), & \text{if $x \in A \setminus S$}
\end{cases}$$

where $g^{-1} : g(B) \to B$ denotes the inverse of $g$ on its image.

In our case the condition for $S \subseteq \langle 0, 1\rangle$ is $$g([0,1] \setminus S) = \langle 0, 1\rangle \setminus S$$

Define $$S = \langle 0, 1\rangle \setminus \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\}$$

Indeed, we have

\begin{align}
g([0, 1] \setminus S) &= g\left(\{0, 1\} \cup \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\}\right) \\
&= \left\{\frac13, \frac23\right\} \cup \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\} \\
&=\bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\} \\
&= \langle 0, 1 \rangle \setminus S
\end{align}

Now we can define $h : A \to B$ as $$h(x) = \begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x \in \langle 0, 1\rangle \setminus \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\}$} \\
3x-1, & \text{if $x \in \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\}$}
\end{cases}$$

$h$ is the desired bijection.

---

To interpret this result in the context of your proof, it suffices to prove that $$A_B = \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\}$$

Indeed, take $g^{n}\left(\frac13\right) \in \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\}$. We have that $g^{n}\left(\frac13\right) \in g(B)$, namely $$g^{n}\left(\frac13\right) = g\left(g^{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)\right)$$

Furthermore, $g^{n-1}\left(\frac13\right) \in \left[\frac13,\frac23\right] \subseteq f(A) = \langle 0, 1\rangle$, the preimage being $g^{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)$. Again,

$$g^{n-1}\left(\frac13\right) = g\left(g^{n-2}\left(\frac13\right)\right)$$

We continue this until we arrive at $\frac13 \in g(B)$. We have $$\frac13 = g(0)$$
Here the process stops because $0 \notin f(A) = \langle 0, 1\rangle$.

Similar argument works for $g^{n}\left(\frac23\right)$, the oldest ancestor being $1$.

For the reverse inclusion, let $x \in A_B$. Therefore, $x$ has an oldest ancestor $b_i \in B$. We have that $b_i = g(b)$ for some $b \in B \setminus f(A) = [0,1] \setminus \langle 0, 1\rangle = \{0, 1\}$. Therefore, $b_i \in \left\{\frac13, \frac23\right\}$ so it must be that $x = g^n\left(\frac13\right)$ or $x = g^n\left(\frac23\right)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$.

Comment: I am pretty sure your final answer is correct. I am just having some trouble interpreting it in the context of the Schroder-Bernstein theorem proof I updated my post with. I upvoted your answer, and I will get back to you...

Comment: @Hat See the edit. I haven't seen your proof of Schröder-Bernstein before but it seems sufficient to prove that $$A_B = \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty \left\{g^n\left(\frac13\right), g^n\left(\frac23\right)\right\}$$
Then $$h(x) = \begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x\in A_A \cup A_\infty$} \\
3x-1, & \text{if $x \in A_B$}
\end{cases}$$ will match the definition above.

Comment: hey, are <0, 1> and (0, 1) the same thing?

Comment: @Hat Yes, it is the open interval.